# How can make pycharm confirm that the redirect from mobile app to the mobile browser was done?

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

Searched everywhere but I fail to find an answer.

Scenario:
Automation script done for an Android application

Pre-req:
Click on a button from the Android application with a Mobile browser redirect

What I want the script to check:
If user was successfully redirected to the Mobile browser by checking if an element from the Mobile browser page is displayed (with a text or link or xpath)

The script is made for the Application but I fail to find the correct code for it to check an element from the browser page

I will post here a small part of code from my automation script for an Android app:

```
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


import time
if __name__ == "__main__":
      desired_cap = {
     "platformName": "android",
     "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
     "appPackage": "com.project.ProjectName",
     "appActivity": ".SplashActivity",
     "automatorName": "UiAutomator2",
 }
 driver = webdriver.Remote ("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",desired_cap)


#Get more gold button check

element = 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath here")
element.click()
print("Step 12. Get more gold button clicked")

pass

#??????Confirmation that Gold store was open IN BROWSER


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//xpath here,*[text()='Choose your payment method']")
#wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "flx-j-c txt-up")))
for i in element:
    if 'Choose your payment method' == i.text:
        print('Step 13. User not on Me tab - PASS')
    else: print('FAIL to redirect the user')
time.sleep(2)
driver.back()

pass
```

Error:
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

I tried to find the element by xpath, class, by text, there is no id to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here,

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//xpath here,*[text()='Choose your payment method']")
```

if you pay attention then you have something like this `xpath here` in `xpath("")`

instead it should be :-

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='Choose your payment method']")
```

Now you will have a `list` here.

```
print(len(element))
```

print the size like this or do whatever you wanna do with the list. It's all upto you.

**Update 1:**
After seeing the HTML, I think this should work for you.

**Xpath**

```
//section[contains(@class,'gold-payment-methods')]/descendant::strong
```

**In code :-**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[contains(@class,'gold-payment-methods')]/descendant::strong")
element.click()
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer.
No error now but even tho I have the iteration it will skip the step mentioned above.
for i in element:

`       if 'Choose your payment method' == i.text:
            print('Step 13. User not on Me tab - PASS')
            time.sleep(2)
        else: print('FAIL to redirect the user')`

I used element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/section[1]") and it works better but still... it will skip the step and it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Sure
`  <section class="cnt-gold-payment-methods flx-column">
        <div class="flx-j-c txt-up"><strong>Choose your payment method</strong></div>
        <div class="flx-w flx-j-c payment-method-list">
                            <div class="payment-method active flx-column js-list-active js-payment-method" data-group="payment-method" data-method="credit_card" data-trackid="NTK:MA:CART:LINK payment method - 'credit_card'">
                    <div class="payment-method-icons flx-c ">
                        <div class="flx-a-c"
`
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Claudaette : Check the updated 1 code above, and let me know if you run into any issues

Comment: Error: **raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters**
Also tried that with the waiting driver, still failing.
What I am trying to understand here is the fact that: if I have only the phone and the app package declared and the script is written for the APP.. will the script make the difference between the app and the mobile browser page? (that doesn't make the script believe that I am still on the app frame and not on browser?)